# Null Pointer Exception in Array of String

Tags: java, arrays, string, jtextarea

I am new to using arrays of objects but can't figure out what I am doing wrong and why I keep getting a Null pointer exception. 
I am trying to create TextReport on JTextArea using array of String input.even i am working on Text spillover to get extra text on next line and it should be display as in table format on JTextArea. my boss told me to make simple report for bank project. For more simplicity. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class testit extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
   String[] colName = new String[]{"Date", "Account.No", "Description", "Deposit", "Withdraw"};
    String A[][] = {{"13/12/2013", "101", "AlphaSoft Infotek Ltd. Nashik", "3000", "0"},
    {"15/12/2013", "103", "Bank Ladger ", "5000", "0"}};
    String[][] B = new String[3][5];

    String[] K = new String[5];

    Container c;
    JTextArea outputArea;
    //JScrollPane js1;

    JButton b;

    public void init() {

        c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        outputArea = new JTextArea(20, 80);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED);
        outputArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border,
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        c.add(outputArea);
        //js1=new JScrollPane(outputArea);
        // add(js1);
        b = new JButton("Show Report");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        c.add(b);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        outputArea.setEditable(false);
        outputArea.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        outputArea.setText(" ");
        outputArea.append("ALPHASOFT -- BANK LADGER , REPORTS.\n\n");
        //outputArea.append("Sr.No");
        for (int j = 0; j < colName.length; j++) {
            outputArea.append("\t" + colName[j]);

        }

        outputArea.append("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            int colv = A[i].length;
            String D = null;
            String Z[][] = A;
           //String Y[]=new String[];
            String Y[] = new String[colv];
            //Y=A;
            for (int ZX = 0; ZX < A[i].length; ZX++) {
                Y[ZX] = A[i][ZX];
            }
            while (Y != null) {

                Z[i] = Y;

                Y = null;
                D = null;
                String bb[] = new String[colv];
                for (int nx = 0; nx < A[i].length; nx++) {
                    Y[nx] = null;

                    //if(Z[i][nx].length()>0){
                    if (Z[i][nx].length() > 20) {
                        D += Z[i][nx].substring(0, 20);
                        Y[nx] = Z[i][nx].substring(20);

                    } else {
                        D += rightpad(Z[i][nx], 20, "R");

                    }
 }

                outputArea.append(D + "\n");

            }

        }
}

    public static String rightpad(String inp, int ln, String rl) {
        String pd = "";
        for (int nx = 0; nx < ln - inp.length(); nx++) {
            pd += " ";
        }
        if (rl == "R") {
            pd = inp + pd;
        } else {

            pd = pd + inp;
        }

        return pd;
    }

}
```

following errors are on console:

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at reportlast.testit.actionPerformed(testit.java:93)

     BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Comment: Check `testit` line 93. Also, capitalize the class name. You don't have to guess when it comes to NullPointerExceptions. They're very easy to diagnose.

Comment: Still i am facing this problem coz of Y=null; but its mendatory to make y as null to perform next operation, so plz help me to solve correctely.@KEYSER

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned `D` and `Y` as `null`

```
        Y = new String[array_length]; // this was null earlier
        D = ""; // this was null earlier
        String bb[] = new String[colv];
        for (int nx = 0; nx < A[i].length; nx++) {
            Y[nx] = null;

            //if(Z[i][nx].length()>0){
            if (Z[i][nx].length() > 20) {
                D += Z[i][nx].substring(0, 20);   // 1
                Y[nx] = Z[i][nx].substring(20);   // 2

            } else {
                D += rightpad(Z[i][nx], 20, "R");  // 3

            }
```

This was the reason why you would have got a null pointer exception at 1, 2 or/and 3

Comment: I appreciate your reply i tried changes as you told me but getting same error.now what plz help me to get out from this thread.@AnkitRustagi.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi D = ""; is much better because you use existing String instead of creating new String object.

Comment: Yeah, that would help since java caches `Strings` thanks, made the edit.

Comment: i got such error on this above programs Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at reportlast.Testit.actionPerformed(Testit.java:95)
 at 
@Ankit Rustagi

Comment: Could you update your code and mark this line as a comment, something like "// error here" since i cant understand what line 95 is.

Comment: while (Y != null) {
                Z[i] = Y;  Y = null; D = " ";
                String bb[] = new String[colv];
                for (int nx = 0; nx < A[i].length; nx++) {
                         if (Z[i][nx].length() > 20) {                         
                        D += Z[i][nx].substring(0, 20);
                        Y[nx] = Z[i][nx].substring(20);//here i got          error s Nullpointer Exception. 
                    } else {
                        D += rightpad(Z[i][nx], 20, "R");
                    } 
                } outputArea.append(D + "\n");
            }//@Ankit